# How can I use scroll on mobile device with API level 8

Tags: cordova

I am developing phonegap application which is running on mobile device with API level 8.
But I have some problems.
Html code is as followed.

```
...
<DIV id="ChList" data-role="content" style="height:230px; overflow:auto">   
...
```

On API level 16 'overflow:auto' is successfully used,but on API level 8 'overflow:auto' is failed.
Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Use Qubic's [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). Not as easy as applying a CSS rule, but not hard either.